# Placing a shape (e.g. ellipse) in the centre of the canvas in KV Language

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm just starting to use Kivy and want to place an ellipse in the centre of of a canvas. Currently I'm using the code below, however only the bottom left 'corner' of the ellipse is at the centre, as the position seems to be determined by the bottom left of each shape.

How can I centre of the canvas in KV language? Thank you in advance.

```
<Widget@BoxLayout>:
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgb: [0.8, 0.8, 1]
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
canvas:
    Color:
        rgb: [0, 0, 0]
    Ellipse
        id: 'El'
        size: [100, 100]
        pos: [self.center_x, self.center_y]
```

Comment: While there may be a nicer approach, without knowing anything about KV, I would just subtract the half of width and height from the center coordinates to get the location of the corner. Something like ```pos: [self.center_x-50, self.center_y-50]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in kivy the `pos` always refers to the bottom left corner. Here's a really simple solution:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
BoxLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: [0.8, 0.8, 1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [0, 0, 0]
        Ellipse
            id: 'El'
            size: [100, 100]
            pos: [self.center_x - 100/2, self.center_y - 100/2]
            """))
```

We just subtract half of the width from the `x` and half of the height from the `y`. This is the simplest solution, but this can be done with [FloatLayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html)  by using `pos_hint`, for example.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to only reference the '100' once for both x and y so that whatever the size it will always appear in the same location? ....or is this something easier and better done in Python?

Comment: If you're going to use a seperate widget for your ellipse (and you probably should), you can set the widget's size and then, in the ellipse, use `self.width` and `self.height`. That's basically what I did, but the size of BoxLayout (which is currently the widget holding the ellipse canvas) is different from the size of the ellipse, it's the size of the whole screen vs (100, 100). Let me know if that makes sense.